# URL Query String Limit

Tags: python, linux, http

I have an application that accesses a script on my server. I pass quite a long query string with my url. The length will change every so often but is always rather long.

**Is there a limit to the length of the url or query string?** Should I be sending the query string parameters in post - will that give me more length?

Important information:

- The server is Linux
- The application code is `Python` and uses `urllib2` to access the script
- The script on the server is a `Python` script

Code used to access script:

```
urllib2.urlopen( "www.site.com?verylongquerystring" )
```

Comment: See this question: [What is the maximum possible length of a query string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string)

Comment: [Maximum URL length is 2,083 characters in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)

Comment: I would suggest using a `POST` HTTP request (not a `GET`) when you need a very long query; I hate URL larger than e.g. 80 or 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 1.1 is defined in RFC 7231: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231

I find no mention of an upper limit on the length of a URL, or a query string, in RFC 7231.

A URL is defined in RFC 3986: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

I find no mention of an upper limit there, either.

It's possible that a particular implementation, like your python library, might impose some limitation, but I think that's unlikely.

It's a pretty safe bet to say that there is no upper limit to the length of a URL, or a query string.